# custom directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My custom directive is not working:

html:

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">

<div>
        <h3>
        <product-title></product-title>
        </h3>
```

...

javascript.app:

...

```
app.directive('productTitle', function(){
    return {
        restrice: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
    };
});
```

...

and my product-title.html:

```
{{product.name}} 
<em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

in my html page i cant see the product name and product price.

I am new in this subject :) 
what should i do to make it work?
please help me.

++thanks everyone for yours answers, it is works! i tried for 3 days to find an answer.. and you did it in 5 min.. thanks! :)++

Comment: Please post your full code for your app definition as well as your directive. Also, what errors show in the JavaScript console (F12)?

Comment: I assume the error will be in your store controller, please post the source code for it.

Comment: Its restrict not restrice (check for spelling.) And error can be in controller as said in above comments

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: Is it possible to share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- restrict is spelled wrong
- Templates for html should have one root,  so you should do something like this

`<div>
    {{product.name}} 
    <em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete running code for your directive in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sisono/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

**JS**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.store = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, price: 132, name: 'abc' },
        { id: 2, price: 127, name: 'def' },
        { id: 3, price: 112, name: 'mno' },
        { id: 4, price: 145, name: 'xyz' }
      ]
    };
  })
  .directive('productTitle', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='AppController'>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <h3>
        <product-title></product-title>
      </h3>
    </li>
</ul>  

</div>

<script id="product-title.html" type="text/ng-template">
  {{product.name}} 
  <em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
</script>
```

Comment: Please accept/ upvote it if it works for your issue :)